# Best way to add li item using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a li item when a button is clicked to a ul list. I have managed to achieve this, but I think there is a better way. Basically I want to add a li item and inside that a label and a button.

Here is my code:

```
var li = $('<li></li>');
var label = $('<label></label>');
var button = $('<button class="check">Check</button>')



$addButton.click(function(){

newItem = $('#new-task').val();
label.text(newItem);

$incompleteTasks.append(li);
li.append(label);
li.append(button);   

});
```

Comment: I thought I did. Which questions are you referring to? I've accepted all the questions that have been answered. If I haven't accepted any answers please do highlight them. Thanks

Comment: You are correct. I think I confused you with another asking similar questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append it like,

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/0gtpygns/1) (Edit : Added text to button as you wanted)

```
$("ul").append(
    $( "<li/>" ).append(
        $('<label/>').append(
            $('<button/>', {
                class : 'check',
                text : 'Button'
            })
         )
    )
);
```

So over here, basically we first append an `li` to `ul`, than we append a `label` to the recently appended `li` and lastly we append a `button` tag to the recently created `label` element and later we use second parameter to separate out the attributes which are later assigned to the `button` tag.

But that's just the cleanliness part, you can directly call a `class` while appending your `button` tag but I wouldn't recommend you to do so.

Just note that you replace the `ul` in the selector with desired `id` or a `class` of your `ul` element.

Comment: How can I add text for the button, where would I put that as an argument?

Comment: @Abdi If your HTML bloats, chaining the appends may seem tedious so in that case it would be better if you assign the HTML to a variable and then append

Comment: Just one other thing I noticed is that it the label doesn't wrap round the li element that is added, it becomes a sibling. Does it need to be reordered? Here's how it looks at the moment: <li>"123"<label>button class="check"></button></label>

Comment: @Abdi Oh wait, then you need to append the text to the `label` element and not the `li`

Answer (score 0):

As of jQuery 1.4 you can pass attributes to a self-closed element like so:

```
jQuery('<li/>', {
   text: 'Text might be some <i>html</i>'
}).appendTo('#mySelector');
```

See the [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) for further information.

This technique will allow you to add individual attributes to your element:

```
jQuery('<li/>', {
   id : 'myUniqueID',
   text: 'Text might be some <i>html</i>'       
}).appendTo('#mySelector');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic sound good ... I would just do 3 things : 
1. prefix all jquery objects with a $ to reognize then easily.
2. keep your html into the function that generate it into the dom
3. take advantage of jQuery's chainability :

```
$addButton.click(function () {

    // prefix jQ objects with a $
    // and keep generated HTML inside the function that generate it into the DOM
    var $li = $('<li></li>'),
        $label = $('<label></label>').text($('#new-task').val()),
        $button = $('<button class="check">Check</button>');

    // take advantage of jQuery's chainability
    $li.append($label).append($button).appendTo($incompleteTasks);

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try these:

```
$('<li>', { class: 'list-item' });
$('<label>');
$('<button>', { class: 'check' });
```

Comment: Why should anyone try this? You should explain what this code do.